# I am trying to import data from my JSON file to the MongoDB database but I keep on encountering a problem

Tags: mongodb, express

```
import-dev-data.js --import /home/manudev/Desktop/Rita/Server/dev-data/import-dev-data.js:9 const DB=process.env.DATABASE.replace("<PASSWORD>", process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD); 



TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/manudev/Desktop/Rita/Server/dev-data/import-dev-data.js:9:31)  
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)  
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)  
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32)  
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930:12)  
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)  
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

Node.js v18.14.0

I tried to import the data this way

```
node import-dev-data.js --import
```

I expected this to appear into my console:

---

Comment: The message says `process.env.DATABASE` is not set (`undefined`), and then attempting to use it in line 9 of the file fails.

Answer (score 0):

**Install package *dotenv* and write this code before using `process.env`**

```
const dotenv = required("dotenv").config()
```